Conditional Logit Model - Utility Structural Estimation - Meta Analysis
I am performing a structural estimation of an utility function across several databases (from distinct articles) using McFadden (2001) framework (see reference).
Each article's database includes N subjects, J choices, which gives a J x N number of rows. Each subject has picked one of the J choices. The data also includes some choice-specific characteristics.
Using this data structure, I estimate the utility parameters through a conditional logit model (CLM) in two ways:
general estimation: I ran a unique CLM on the whole dataset. Notice that J can change across articles
article-wise estimation: I ran one CLM for each article, and average out the resulting estimates
However, the two methods give substantially different results.
Anyone has an idea on which procedure (if any) would be best for providing a meta-estimation of these parameters?
Reference: McFadden, D. (2001). Economic choices. American economic review, 91(3), 351-378.

If you fitted different models per article (taking advantage of the different J) then I would expect the results to be different.

Thanks @mdewey. Just to be more precise: in the article-wise estimation, I fitted the same model specification for each article. Can you please clarify your argument?

Now you have clarified what you did my point no longer has any value.
